# Using Java Generics to recurse over an object with a list of objects (each with another list of objects)

Tags: java, generics

I have three interfaces:

```
public interface Combinable<V> {
    V add(V other);
}

public interface Sublistable<V> {
    boolean hasSublist();
    List<V> getSublist();
    void setSublist(List<V> sublist);
}

public interface HasUniqueIdentifier {
    String getUniqueIdentifier();
}
```

and 4 classes that implement some or all of these interfaces:

```
public class Grandparent implements HasUniqueIdentifier, 
                                    Sublistable<Parent>, 
                                    Combinable<Grandparent> 
{   List<Parent> sublist; ... }

public class Parent implements HasUniqueIdentifier, 
                               Sublistable<Child>, 
                               Combinable<Parent> 
{   List<Child> sublist; ... }

public class Child implements HasUniqueIdentifier, 
                              Sublistable<Grandchild>, 
                              Combinable<Child> 
{   List<Grandchild> sublist; ...  }

public class Grandchild implements HasUniqueIdentifier, 
                                   Combinable<Grandchild> 
{    }
```

I would like to have a generic method that does the following:

```
public <V, T extends HasUniqueIdentifier & Combinable<T> & Sublistable<V>> 
List<T> combine(List<T> items) {
    Multimap<String, T> similarItemMap = HashMultimap.create();
    for (T item: items) {
        similarItemMap.put(item.getUniqueIdentifier(), item);
    }

    List<T> output = new ArrayList<T>();
    for (Collection<T> similarCollection : similarItemMap.asMap().values()) {
        List<T> similarItems = Lists.newArrayList(similarCollection);
        T source = similarItems.get(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < similarItems.size(); i++) {
            source = source.add(similarItems.get(i));
        }
        output.add(source);
    }

    for (T item : output) {
        if (item.hasSublist()) {
            item.setSublist(combine(item.getSublist));
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Realizing that this could create an infinite loop (unless the bottom class -- Grandchild -- implemented Sublistable and set `hasSublist() { return false; }`, or something), as well as the fact that this method is kind of crazy with generics, I have to ask: Is there some way that I can rewrite this a bit so that I can call the method in this way:

`combine(listOfGrandparents)`

or should I give up on this being one method and try to refactor it in a better way?

---

**Edit:**
To better explain what it is that I'm trying to do, I have a list of objects of type `A`.  Each object `a` has a list of objects of type `B`.  Each object `b` has a list of objects of type `C`, and so on, until eventually type `T` (for some varying level of `T`) doesn't have a sublist anymore.

Each type basically has three things that it needs to do for a "merge" or "combine" method:

1. Collect all "like" items into a container, using the `item.getUniqueIdentifier()` method
2. Combine all the like items into one item, using the `source.add(other)` method
3. If the item has a sublist, do a merge on the sublist.

Since each item behaves so similarly, it would be nice if I could use a single method instead of having to have `n` methods, one for each type.  Unfortunately, since none of the types are guaranteed to be the same (other than having implemented some or all of the given interfaces above), creating a generic method proves to be difficult.  Is there some way to do this that I'm missing?

---

**Edit 2:**
I've found a method that *kind of* works.  Basically, it changes to this:

```
public <V extends HasUniqueIdentifier & Combinable<V>, 
        T extends HasUniqueIdentifier & Combinable<T>> 
List<T> combine(List<T> items) {
    Multimap<String, T> similarItemMap = HashMultimap.create();
    for (T item: items) {
        similarItemMap.put(item.getUniqueIdentifier(), item);
    }

    List<T> output = new ArrayList<T>();
    for (Collection<T> similarCollection : similarItemMap.asMap().values()) {
        List<T> similarItems = Lists.newArrayList(similarCollection);
        T source = similarItems.get(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < similarItems.size(); i++) {
            source = source.add(similarItems.get(i));
        }
        output.add(source);
    }

    for (T item : output) {
        if (item instanceof Sublistable<?>) {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            Sublistable<V> sublistableItem = ((Sublistable<V>)sublistableItem);
            if (sublistableItem.hasSublist()) {
                sublistableItem.setSublist(combine(sublistableItem.getSublist));
            }
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Unfortunatey, this method requires both a `@SupressWarnings` and an `instanceof`, which I would like to avoid if possible.  I haven't found anything else, though, yet.

Comment: If you already ask yourself this question, this probably is a good sign that a refactoring would be wise. Especially, considering that other people will at some point have to understand a method that the author himself calls "crazy" ;)

Comment: Combinable doesn't seem to be used anywhere, instead of hasSublist you could just check whether getSublist returns a list that is empty or null.  But I would start with editing your post and adding a paragraph to explain what you want the method to do for that's unclear (and therefore a good indication that refactoring is a good idea)

Comment: @bigge: Yeah, the alternative is to have `combine(List<Grandparent> items)`, `combine(List<Parent> items)`, `combine(List<Child> items)`, and `combine(List<Grandchild> items)`, though, which doesn't sit well with me either.

@beny23: `Combinable` is used in the `source.add(similarItems.get(i))` line.  I'll update the description with what it is that I'm trying to do exactly, as well.

Comment: It seems to me as if you are trying to implement `flatMap`. Given a list of grandparents, you want a list of all their "elements", which happen to be parents. Given a list of parents you want a list of all their "elements" and so on. If you called it twice, as in `combine(combine(grandparents))` you'd get children. Thrice and you'd get grandchildren. I'm completely bewildered by the `setSublist(...)` though.

Comment: @BenSchulz: It's not quite a flatten.  The hierarchy is still preserved.  It just finds like elements and combines them, and then finds like elements in their children, and combines them, and so on.  It is possible that the entire tree would be kept exactly the same, assuming that every item, subitem, and so on had a unique identifier (in comparison to the other nodes that share the same parent, at least) at its level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first solution is fine, given that `GrandChild implements Sublistable<Void>` vacuously. The tree is more uniform and easier to handle recursively. You may also want to have one merged `interface Node<T,V> extends HasUniqueIdentifier, Combinable<T>, Sublistable<V>{}`

If you don't want `GrandChild implements Sublistable`, your 2nd solution is also fine. A single `instanceof` to test a marker interface isn't a sin. The code can be rewritten as

```
public <T extends HasUniqueIdentifier & Combinable<T>> 
List<T> combine(List<T> items) 
{
    ...
    List<T> output = new ArrayList<T>();
    ...

    for (T item : output) {
        if (item instanceof Sublistable<?>) 
            combineSublist((Sublistable<?>)item);

    return output;
}

private <V> void combineSublist(Sublistable<V> sublistableItem)
{
    if (sublistableItem.hasSublist()) {
        sublistableItem.setSublist(combine(sublistableItem.getSublist));
}
```

Comment: Does this make the assumption that `V` has to extend `HasUniqueIdentifier` & `Combinable<V>` (in order to make the call to combine again)?  Also, does this put us under the assumption that every `Sublistable<T>` has to have such a `T` that implements those interfaces as well?

Comment: good point. `Sublistable` is not constrained enough so that its sublist can be combine()-ed. ideally we want to test `if item instanceof Sublistable<? extends Combinable<?>>` but there's no easy way to do that. So you probably want to strengthen `Sublistable to Sublistable<V extends Combinable<V>>`. If that's not possible, maybe a new subinterface `Foo<V extends Combinable<V>> extends Sublistable<V>`, and `Parent implements Foo<Child>`, so the code can test `item instanceof Foo`